# Extended regular expression new line

Tags: regex, grep

I seem to match two things using extended regular expressions:

1. Newline. I have tried `[ \n]`, `[ \\n]`, both don't work
2. Negative lookahead for string "timeout". I have tried (?!timeout)

Can anyone please point out the correct way?

Comment: If it is against a DOS encoded text file, or may be used against one at some point, try matching [\n\r] to allow for carriage return as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Newline

If you're using bash, you can write `$'\n'`. This gets expanded by the shell, not the program, so it's more reliable than other options.

If you're using dash (e.g., inside a shell script), you can always use a literal quoted newline:

```
'
'
```

Not elegant, but it works.

#### Lookahead

You'll have to use Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (`-P`), since extended regular expressions do not support lookaheads.

Oftentimes, it's sufficient to *mimic* negative lookaheads.

Using grep's `-v` switch usually accomplishes this:

```
grep -E 'PATTERN' | grep -vE 'PATTERNtimeout'
```

is equivalent to

```
grep -P 'PATTERN(?!timeout)'
```

To mimic `(?!timeout)` inside another expression, you can use this subexpression:

```
(($|[^t])|t($|[^i])|ti($|[^m])|tim($|[^e])|time($|[^o])|timeo($|[^u])|timeou($|[^t]))
```

- `($|[^t])` string ends here or first character is not **t**.
- `t($|[^i])` string ends after **t** or second character is not **i**.
- `ti($|[^m])` string ends after **ti** or third character is not **tim**.
- ...

If any of the above matches, the string is not **timeout**.